# myapp.com/@username url in rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, social-networking

Hi I have a simple rails question that I am simply unable to figure out. like the title says, I want to get my users controller show page to have the myapp.com/@username url but I don't know how to do this. My knowledge of routes must be fundamentally flawed.

my links now usually look like this:

```
<%= link_to "#{@user.username}", :controller => "users", :action => "show", :username => @user.username %>
```

obviously this is not ideal.  I'd like them to look like this.

```
<%= link_to "#{@user.username}", user_path(@user) %>
```

but I don't know what to do.  Nested routes doesn't seem to be the way.

my routes are setup like this:

```
map.connect '/:username', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

but this seemingly just allows me to do what I do now, doesn't let me actually route through there.  Any suggestions? PS this is a rails 2.3.8 app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your route is correct, however you did not give it a name:

```
map.USER '/:username', :controller => :users, :action => :show
```

All caps from me to highlight what you need to change. Now you can call `user_path(:username => @user.username)`

Answer (score 0):

In your routes file, you need to setup the resource:

```
map.resources :users
```

Now you'll have the nice named routes like `user_path(@user)` to show the user page, and so on.  If you don't want restful routes, you can also just create a single named route:

```
map.user '/users/:id', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

And `user_path(@user)` will work as well.

By the way, your login example above is incorrect.  First, ":login" is being interpreted by the routing engine as a variable, but it's not being used. Also, you wouldn't want the users#show page to be the login page.  For starters, show what user?  they haven't logged in yet.  I hope this helps!

Comment: yes, I understand how to set up routes.  I am trying to set up a specific route, what you have told me to do will give me the url for:

Comment: myapp.com/@username.  What you have told me gives you myapp.com/users/@username, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you were going for - especially with the ":login" parameter you had previously.  The other answer looks like it has it right.

Comment: my apologies, it was my fault, I was copying and pasting from my app which actually uses "login" as the users username in the DB but I missed that one when I was changing them over to a more readable format. Sorry!